# Can Erlang Cowboy set up PHP framework?

Tags: php, wordpress, erlang, cowboy

Cowboy is a Small, fast, modular HTTP server written in Erlang.

http://ninenines.eu

Can we set up PHP framework, such as wordpress on that? How?

Comment: It looks like just a plain old high speed http server ie no server side processing its all html 5 and new techs etc so basically just static html + css + js.  which means you could use it to do an ajax request to another webserver running on the local machine on a different port some high speed php enabled server cherokee, nginx, apache etc

Comment: i think this question fits SO, cowboy is more a HTTP library than a server you install globally like apache. Running PHP on top of it requires programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can try to run your PHP application over fastcgi 
https://github.com/unix1/cowboy_fcgi